# What is wrong with this JOIN syntax?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, cross-join

If I run this SQL code in my PostgreSQL database, it works fine:

```
select 
    e.type_id,
    s.copy_destination || '\'
FROM 
    ebooks.ebooks e, ebooks.static_text s
WHERE
    e.status_id = 1
```

But when I add the join, everything goes pear-shaped. So if I run:

```
select 
    e.type_id,
    s.copy_destination || '\'
FROM 
    ebooks.ebooks e, ebooks.static_text s
join 
    ebooks.types y
on 
    e.type_id = y.type_id
WHERE
    e.status_id = 1
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "e"
LINE 11:     e.type_id = y.type_id
             ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "e", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 159
```

I've tried using the full reference (`ebooks.eboooks.type_id`) instead of just `e`, but nothing changed. I still got the "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table 'e'" - note that it still thinks I'm trying to reference table 'e'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried changing the sequence of tables in FROM clause?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that a comma (`,`) in the `FROM` list is almost, but not quite the same as a `CROSS JOIN`. Explicit join syntax binds before commas or, in other words, the comma separates stronger. So the reference to `e.type_id` is placed where that table is still out of scope. See:

- [Why does this implicit join get planned differently than an explicit join?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167219/3684)

You can replace the comma with an otherwise equivalent `CROSS JOIN`, to silence the error:

```sql
SELECT e.type_id, s.copy_destination || '\'
FROM   ebooks.ebooks e
CROSS  JOIN ebooks.static_text s               -- !!!
JOIN   ebooks.types y ON e.type_id = y.type_id
WHERE  e.status_id = 1;
```

Rearranged to make clearer:

```sql
SELECT e.type_id, s.copy_destination || '\'
FROM   ebooks.ebooks      e
-- JOIN   ebooks.types       y USING (type_id)
CROSS  JOIN ebooks.static_text s    --   now you might as well use a comma again!
WHERE  e.status_id = 1
```

I commented out the join to `ebooks.types` completely as it seems to be dead freight - assuming referential integrity is guaranteed with an FK constraint.

The issue remains that the table `static_text` is joined to the rest *without condition*, which produces a Cartesian Product of both sets. Typically not what you want ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    select 
        e.type_id,
        s.copy_destination ||
        '\'
    FROM 
        ebooks.static_text s Join  ebooks.ebooks e
on s.ref_id = e.id
    join 
        ebooks.types y
    on 
        e.type_id = y.type_id
    WHERE
        e.status_id = 1
```

Change the query to this format then it should work.
ref_id and id are the names of joining columns of 2 tables. Change that way because the  order of tables in query and multiple joining columns (more than 1 column get join) in both tables can be the reason for this error.